# Facebook SDK and PHP Array

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I am working with the Facebook SDK and PHP. Everything is working fine, but I am having trouble with one part, which is storing a specific field value into a variable.

Here is the code, which gets and prints the info.

```
if ($session){ //if we have the FB session

    $user_profile = (new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me/accounts?fields=id,name,access_token'))->execute()->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());
    //do stuff below, save user info to database etc.
    echo "Session Set.";

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($user_profile); //Or just print all user details
    $variable = print_r($user_profile, TRUE);
    echo '</pre>';

    // How do I get the first 'id', 'name', and 'access_token'
    // How do I get the second 'id', 'name', and 'access_token'
}
```

And here is what prints (I replaced the actual data with XXXX for obvious reasons):

```
Session Set.
Facebook\GraphUser Object
(
    [backingData:protected] => Array
        (
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => XXXXXXXX
                            [name] => XXXXXXXX
                            [access_token] => XXXXXXXXX
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => XXXXXXXXX
                            [name] => XXXXXXXXX
                            [access_token] => XXXXXXXXX
                        )

                )

            [paging] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [cursors] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [before] => XXXXXXX
                            [after] => XXXXXXX
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

How do I take [id], [name], and [access_token] and store them in variables so I can eventually save them into a db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you're trying to integrate with the Facebook SDK using PHP, I highly recommend reading through Facebook's developer guide on it here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted

Here is a very helpful YouTube tutorial on using the Facebook SDK:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P9ktjGNeAzg

Here is his GitHub files regarding the Facebook SDK:

https://github.com/sohaibilyas/facebook-php-sdk-v5

The file that wound up leading me to figure out how to get a Facebook Page ID and Access_Token was add-page-tab.php

Here is the piece of the code that will provide you with your info:

```
$pages = $fb->get('/me/accounts');
$pages = $pages->getGraphEdge()->asArray();
?>

<form action="XXXXXXXXXX" method="POST">
<select name="page" single>

<?php
foreach ($pages as $key) {
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $key['id']; ?>"><?php echo $key['name']; ?></option>
    <?php
}

?>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $page = $fb->get('/' . $_POST['page'] . '?fields=access_token, name, id');
    $page = $page->getGraphNode()->asArray();

    echo "Access Token: " .$page['access_token'] . "<br/><br/>";

    echo "Page Id: " . $page['id'];

    // print_r($page);

}
```

You can then easily store the variables into a DB, SESSION, COOKIE, etc...and carry out different functions.

Hope this helps someone. My best advice is go through the tutorials and read the Facebook guide in full. You'll save a lot of time and headache not trying to take a shortcut!